# Ordering columns in datatable

Tags: vb.net

So, I have this function that takes in a datatable and orders the users by two columns. (Rank and OrderCount)

```
Function DetermineBestUser(ByVal usertable As DataTable)
    Dim bestchoice As DataRow()

    For u = 0 To usertable.Rows.Count - 1
        If Not DoesProcessorNeedOrders(usertable.Rows(u).Item("UserName"), usertable.Rows(u).Item("Amount")) Then
            usertable.Rows(u).Delete()
        End If
    Next

    bestchoice = usertable.Select("", "Rank ASC, OrderCount DESC")

    If IsDBNull(usertable) Then
        Console.WriteLine("No user is qualified for this order at this moment")
    End If
    Return bestchoice(0)(0).ToString
End Function
```

The problem is that sometimes this function works correctly and gives me the user with the HIGHEST Rank (1 or 2) and the LOWEST OrderCount (0 - 30+). However, sometimes it does not return the correct person. The only thing i've seen that fixes this is changing the "Ordercount DESC" to "OrderCount ASC"; however, this change only works for that specific order and then it's back to returning the wrong person.

---

I have some test runs that will show this in more detail: R1 & R2 = Rank 1 or 2 / "OrderCount"

```
Rank ASC, Ordercount ASC
#1
dane-R2 / 12
jerm-R1 / 15
tulsa-R1 / 5
---picks Jerm (should pick tulsa)
#2
Dane-R2 / 14
Jerm-R2 / 15
Kate- R2 / 15
---picks Dane 
#3
Dane-R2 / 15
Jerm-R2 / 5
Kate-R2 / 5
---picks dane (should pick Jerm or Kate)
```

---

```
Rank ASC, Ordercount DESC
#1
dane-R2 / 12
jerm-R1 / 15
tulsa-R1 / 5
---picks Tulsa 
#2
Dane-R2 / 14
Jerm-R2 / 15
Kate- R2 / 15
---picks Jerm (should pick Dane)
#3
Dane-R2 / 15
Jerm-R2 / 5
Kate-R2 / 5
---picks Jerm
```

Comment: Wehre are the variables `username, amount` declared?

Comment: oh, i just simplified those. I'm grabbing those from a table. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Is it possible OrderCount is a text value? When sorting text (a lexical sort), 15 is less than 5, but it looks character by character and returns a result at the first difference.

Comment: Rank and OrderCount are both set as Integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's treating your OrderCount as a **string** value, instead of a numeric value, and therefore sorting it lexically instead of numerically. What type is the column?

You'll have the same problem with your Rank column, if you get enough ranks to get to two digits.

Also, for example #2 from your second block, you have this:

```
#2
Dane-R2 / 14
Jerm-R2 / 15
Kate- R2 / 15
---picks Jerm (should pick Dane)
```

In this case, Jerm is a correct pick. The Ranks all match, and so it falls to the OrderCount column, from which it should pick one of the 15's if you're sorting descending.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
Dim bestChoices = From row In usertable.AsEnumerable()
                  Let Rank = row.Field(Of Int32)("Rank")
                  Let OrderCount = row.Field(Of Int32)("OrderCount")
                  Let UserName = row.Field(Of String)("UserName")
                  Let Amount = row.Field(Of Int32)("Amount")
                  Where Not DoesProcessorNeedOrders(UserName, Amount)
                  Order By Rank Ascending, OrderCount Descending

If bestChoices.Any() Then
    Dim bestChoice = bestChoices.First()
    Return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", bestChoice.UserName, bestChoice.Rank, bestChoice, OrderCount)
Else
    Return "No user is qualified for this order at this moment"
End If
```

Comment: As soon as it gets to the "Dim BestChoice = bestchoice.First()" line, it jumps back to "Let Rank = row.Field(of Int32)(0)" and then an error occurs "Specified cast is not valid."  ? ? ?

Comment: What type are your columns? I've presumed that Rank and OrderCount are integers. If they are strings you have to cast them to string and then use `Int32.Parse`. The `Field` method is strongly typed. I've also edited my answer to  take your "delete-row"-logic into account and use the column name instead of it's ordinal as in my first version.